# How to get all the tracks of a Spotify playlist

Tags: python

I'm trying to get all the tracks from 2 playlists into a CSV file. However, in both playlists, even though I increase the offset parameter by 100 in each query, the first 100 songs of both playlists are returned. So the page is never changed. What could be the problem?

```
import spotipy, json, csv
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

data_file = open('data.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(data_file)
writer.writerow(['track_num', 'track_id', 'track_name', 'first_artist'] + ['liked'])

playlist_ids = [
    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', # playlist 1
    'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy' # playlist 2
]

for playlist_id in playlist_ids:
    offset_n = 0
    total = 100
    while offset_n < total:
        tracks_response = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id, offset=offset_n)
        tracks_json = json.dumps(tracks_response)
        tracks_data = json.loads(tracks_json)
        if offset_n == 0:
            total = tracks_data['tracks']['total']
        for track in tracks_data['tracks']['items']:
            track_id = track['track']['id']
            track_name = track['track']['name']
            first_artist = track['track']['artists'][0]['name']
            if playlist_id == playlist_ids[0]:
                writer.writerow([row_num, track_id, track_name, first_artist] + [1])
            else:
                writer.writerow([row_num, track_id, track_name, first_artist] + [0])
        offset_n += 100

data_file.close()
```

Comment: Looks like your loop only run once. Change total to 1000 and try it again.

Comment: That's not it. I printed offset_n in every iteration too. And it gives the expected values.

Comment: I'm about to cry 

Comment: Did you change the total to 1000 and it didn't work?

Comment: It didn't work. So I tried a different approach and used next() to get the next pages instead. It finally worked but now I get ReadTimeout error in the middle of runtime and I still couldn't write the whole file. 

Answer (score 0):

The `playlist_tracks` method returns a paginated result with details of the tracks of a playlist.
So you need to iterate over all pages to get the full data.

You can use this example as a reference:

```
def get_all_tracks_from_playlist(playlist_id)
    tracks_response = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id)
    tracks = tracks_response["items"]
    while tracks_response["next"]:
        tracks_response = sp.next(tracks_response)
        tracks.extend(tracks_response["items"])

    return tracks
```

Regarding the `ReadTimeout` exception you have mentioned in the comments:

Spotify client accepts `requests_timeout` and `retries` as arguments, according to the documentation the default values are `requests_timeout=5`, and `retries=3`
You can extend them as you wish to decrease the chance you will get the `ReadTimeout` exception.

As a start you can double the request timeout to 10 seconds, and change the retries to 5:

```
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager, requests_timeout=10, retries=5)
```